# React testing - How can I mock or inject data in the store to be provided as props to component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm using jest and `react-testing-library` to provide unit test coverage for my app.

I use this handy helper function Kent C. Dodds showed in one of his videos:

```
const renderWithRedux = ui => ({
    ...render(<Provider store={store}>{ui}</Provider>),
    store,
});
```

I use when I am testing connected components.

I am running into an issue where in order to render a component I needed some data fetched to accuaratly resolve a test, or atleast inject mock data into the store. I am failing to do so

this is my test:

```
test('navbar accepts props', async () => {
    /**
     * Something I was testing
     */
    const functionToTest = () => async dispatch => {
        dispatch(fetchTickets());
    };

    functionToTest();
    const isReady = true;
    const mockData = {
        sessionInformation: {
            ticket: { label: 'Total Tickets' },
            sessionDuration: { sessionLabel: 'Session Duration', duration: 42 },
            equipment: { type: 'Desktop', operatingSystem: 'Windows' },
        },
        component: { isReady },
        tickets: {
            ticketPayload: [
                {
                    number: '1020312039',
                    shortDescription: 'Accessories',
                    status: 'Active',
                    createdOnEpoch: 1512322200000,
                },
            ],
        },
    };

    const data = renderWithRedux(<Navbar props={mockData} />);
});
```

The component I am testing:

```
const NavBar = ({
    openTickets: { label },
    sessionDuration: { sessionLabel, duration },
    tickets: { ticketPayload = [] },
    isReady,
}) => (!isReady ? (
    <Container>
        <LogoContainer>
            <Logo src={logo} alt="logo" />
            <Header>Service Desk</Header>
        </LogoContainer>

        <SessionInformation className="session">
            <NavbarInfo className="session-info">
                <p>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon="ticket-alt" className="ticketIcon" />
                    {label}
                </p>
                <p>{`${ticketPayload.length} tickets`}</p>
            </NavbarInfo>
            <NavbarInfo last className="session-info">
                <p>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon="clock" className="ticketIcon" />
                    {sessionLabel}
                </p>
                <p>{`${duration} minutes`}</p>
            </NavbarInfo>
            {hasTokens() && (
                <Button type="submit" onClick={() => console.log('notes')}>
                        Notepad
                </Button>
            )}
        </SessionInformation>
    </Container>
) : (
    <LoaderContainer>
        <RingLoader size={100} />
    </LoaderContainer>
));
```

I need to make length calculations with `ticketPayload` however the main store is taking priority. Since that information has not been fetched, `ticketPayload`'s is 0. I want to be able to atleast mock the data to be passed but haven't had any luck using props, as the store takes precedence.

Hope anyone can beam a light of help or share some guidance. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: First thing to consider - the object you're passing to NavBar via props is not providing the props it needs. For example, NavBar expects that 'isReady' attribute but you are passing it as an attribute of another object, component = { isReady }

Comment: :/ that doesn't really solve my issue at it seems that those props are not doing anything. Since Navbar is connected to the redux store, it receives by precedence the store's props, and these props are empty arrays until they are fetched. I need it to take the mock data for testing purposes. Hope that makes sense @leosteffen

Comment: I'm not the best person to help with redux specifics, but I'd have 1) the component tested in isolation rather than connected to redux and 2) have the fetchTickets() function tested on its own. This way you can make sure your individual parts work as they should until you find out if/how to test them together.

Comment: That makes sense. I do have each tested separaretly. I test my actions with `redux-mock-stor` and reducers separately.. I guess I wanted to simulate and test an end to end experience with the component lol

Comment: I see, just make sure you don't end up testing redux :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a helper function to wrap my components with redux.

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import initialState from '../store/initialState';

const mockStore = (state = initialState) => configureMockStore()(state);

export const testableComponent = (component, state) =>
  (<Provider store={mockStore(state)}>{component}</Provider>);
```

And then you can call it just like this, passing your state

```
testableComponent(<YourComponent />, {yourUpdatedMockedState})
```

Answer (score 3):

The official [Writing Tests](https://redux.js.org/recipes/writing-tests#connected-components) doc from `Redux` recommends this approach:

> But sometimes you want to test just the rendering of the component, without a Redux store.
>
> In order to be able to test the...component itself without having to deal with the decorator, we recommend you to also export the undecorated component

In other words...export `NavBar` as a **named export** so you can access it in your tests.

Then you can test it directly as a simple UI component that just renders based on the `props` you give it.

Comment: That makes complete sense as well! Thanks for sharing :)

Comment: if you `import { Component } from "./Component";` you will not need to wrap with store/provider.